# IIS7 FASTCGI PHP CODEIGNITER Windows 500 internal error

Tags: php, codeigniter, iis-7, fastcgi

First of all the web project works perfectly on linux server.

I'm trying to run my web codeigniter project on windows server 2008 with IIS7.5 configured with PHP5.3 / FASTCGI.

When i run the project after putting it in wwwroot/project1

it does not work. It gives a 500 internal server error :

```
Module: FastCgiModule
Notification: ExecuteRequestHandler
Hander: PHP_via_FastCGI
Error Code: 0x000000000
```

I check the permission settings on project1 and it does have iisusr.

.php works perfectly
phpinfo.php works though.

I did a simple mysql_connect .php script and it works perfectly.

Its just for the CI project not working.

Any special settings needed on IIS for CI projects to work on IIS/FastCGI ?
Also i do not have any .htaccess file , not sure why it does not work... Any suggestions?

Anything gotta do with url rewriting or something?

Comment: PHP error logging on? If so, check if there's an error in there. Otherwise this is an IIS question.

Comment: doesnt seem like a php error.. i suppose is CI issues with IIS7/FastCGI ..still stuck

Answer (score 0):

my server admin reinstalled IIS with php 5.2

and now we are have a different error, but at least this is something more useful...

```
is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(application) is not within the allowed path(s): (C:\inetpub\wwwroot) in
```

What are the permission settings needed for CI on IIS?

Comment: New questions should be asked as new questions, and not as answers to your original question.  You should also mark the fact that you reinstalled IIS and that fixed it, as the answer to your question.  Finally, the problem you have here about open_basedir can be resolved by checking your PHP.ini and configuring appropriately.  That is not a permissions error, in the sense of file permissions.